# Jquery .Append <div> and swapping with Flex Box Order - Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have an Ecommerce software that a company i work for is using. I'm trying to change the layout that the software outputs for variable products.

Sadly i do not have the ability to change the HTML. My plan is to .append a div using Jquery then swapping the Selection Menus at the bottom of the layout to the new created div using the flexbox order rule. [Flex Rule Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) This in theory would allow me to move the selection menus into the row above them, and place them right below the forms on the left side of the page, and keep the proof image on the right side still. Here is a visual example...

[image]

As you can see they have the layout set up with an un-ordered list, and the sections are list elements within the un-ordered list.

[image]

The code i'm trying to acheive this with is..

```
$('#right-column').append('<div id="selection-swap">Swap Here</div>');
```

Could someone take a look at my Codepen and let me know what i'm doing wrong here?

[Codepen Here](http://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/WxaoXW)

Comment: from the codepen code, i dont see the list items, i think code is missing

Comment: Missing from your images, code snippet and codepen is the... `order` property.

Comment: I did not even get to that part because the .append i added does not seem to be even adding the #selection-swap. I was hoping to get the .append to work first.

Comment: @StinkyTofu in your codepen you dont add jquery cdn. then your append div will place on right column.